# R flatten nested data.table

Tags: r, nested, data.table

I have nested data table, what is the best way to flatten nested tables to one data.table? Note, that nested tables can have unequal length, so tidyr::unnest() does not work.

Code example:

```
NestedTable <- data.table(
  COLUMN1 = c('var1', 'var2','var3'),
  COLUMN2 = c('col2a', 'col2b', 'col2c')
)

# add nested data.tables
NestedTable[ , NESTED_COL := list(list(data.table(
  COLUMN4 = c(
    'A', 'B'
  ), 
  COLUMN5 = c(
    'C', 'D'
  )
)))]

NestedTable[ , NESTED_COL2 := list(list(data.table(
  COLUMN6 = c(
    'A', 'B','C'
  ), 
  COLUMN7 = c(
    'C', 'D','E'
  )
)))]

#      COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN4 COLUMN5 COLUMN6 COLUMN7
# 1:    var1   col2a   A       C       A       C
# 2:    var1   col2a   B       D       B       D
# 3:    var1   col2a                   C       E
# 4:    var2   col2b   A       C       A       C
# 5:    var2   col2b   B       D       B       D
# 6:    var2   col2b                   C       E
# 7:    var3   col2c   A       C       A       C
# 8:    var3   col2c   B       D       B       D
# 9:    var3   col2c                   C       E
```

Comment: `tidyr::unnest(NestedTable)`

Comment: great, thanks a lot! is it also an efficient function to nest it again? So assume that I want to nest output table - column4 and column5 to nested data.table by column1 and column2

Comment: perhaps `tidyr:nest()`? but since it's another question, you should make it another question.

Comment: tidyr::nest() make nested tbl_df structure, not data.table. Thanks for suggestion, I will make it as new question.

Comment: As far as I can only post once every 90 minutes, I would be grateful to discuss here any ideas for most efficient way of nesting data.table again inside data.table.

Comment: Re "most efficient way", it depends how you're constructing it. If every row contains the same table, your way is fine. If each row's table is different, maybe use `.(Map(...))` or `.(lapply(...))`. I use the latter with `fread`: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/data.table/4456/using-list-columns-to-store-data/15561/reading-in-many-related-files#t=201611041516121977677 The time spent on the assignment of the DT is a lot less than the fread...

Comment: not pretty at all, but probably fast: `rbindlist(NestedTable$NESTED_COL, id = T)[, cbind(NestedTable[.id, -"NESTED_COL"], .SD)]` (uses 1.9.7+)

Answer (score 13):

We can try with `unlist`

```
NestedTable[, unlist(NESTED_COL, recursive=FALSE), .(COLUMN1, COLUMN2)]
```

Comment: How can you keep NESTED_COL2?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidyr` :

```r
NestedTable %>%
  tidyr::unnest(NESTED_COL)
#>    COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN4 COLUMN5
#> 1:    var1   col2a       A       C
#> 2:    var1   col2a       B       D
#> 3:    var2   col2b       A       C
#> 4:    var2   col2b       B       D
#> 5:    var3   col2c       A       C
#> 6:    var3   col2c       B       D
```

Comment: it does not work, when there are few nested data.table different length, ERROR: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think a mix of `tidyr::unnest_wider` and `tidyr::unnest_longer` should work. `unnest_wider` produces a table columns 1-7. `unnest_longer` unnests each list.

```
NestedTable%>%
  unnest_wider(NESTED_COL)%>%
  unnest_wider(NESTED_COL2)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN4   COLUMN5   COLUMN6   COLUMN7  
#  <chr>   <chr>   <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>   
#1 var1    col2a   <chr [2]> <chr [2]> <chr [3]> <chr [3]>
#2 var2    col2b   <chr [2]> <chr [2]> <chr [3]> <chr [3]>
#3 var3    col2c   <chr [2]> <chr [2]> <chr [3]> <chr [3]>


NestedTable%>%
  unnest_wider(NESTED_COL)%>%
  unnest_wider(NESTED_COL2)%>%
  unnest_longer(COLUMN4)%>%
  unnest_longer(COLUMN5)%>%
  unnest_longer(COLUMN6)%>%
  unnest_longer(COLUMN7)
# A tibble: 108 x 6
#   COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN4 COLUMN5 COLUMN6 COLUMN7
#   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
# 1 var1    col2a   A       C       A       C      
# 2 var1    col2a   A       C       A       D      
# 3 var1    col2a   A       C       A       E      
# 4 var1    col2a   A       C       B       C      
# 5 var1    col2a   A       C       B       D      
# 6 var1    col2a   A       C       B       E      
# 7 var1    col2a   A       C       C       C      
# 8 var1    col2a   A       C       C       D      
# 9 var1    col2a   A       C       C       E      
#10 var1    col2a   A       D       A       C      
# ... with 98 more rows
```